# TypeError in postgres Upsert

Tags: postgresql, jupyter, upsert

I want to do an upset in postgres (insert or update)

If a user_id does not exist in the table, I want to insert a line with user_id=user_id, first_date=date, last_date=date. But if the user already exists, I want to update only the last_date with date.

I was getting an error so I tried to simplify the insert with:

```
pd.read_sql("INSERT INTO table (user_id, first_date, last_date) 
             VALUES ( "+str(user_id)+", '"+date+"','"+date+"')
             ON CONFLICT (user_id)
             DO NOTHING", conn)
```

But I'm getting this error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

And I can't understand what is wrong...

I'm using Jupyter and Postgres v11

Answer (score 0):

read_sql expects a query returning data. Your `INSERT` doesn't.

You might use the execute function [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#id4):

```
from pandas.io import sql
sql.execute('INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(?, ?, ?)', engine,
        params=[('id', 1, 12.2, True)])
```

or you could add a `RETURNING` clause to the query. [See the excellent postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).